# How to set up an interface with an abstract member variable in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a Flutter application and wanted to define a common scheme for all my pages. All pages should have a static id variable that I use for routing with named routes. (instead of having to instanciate `MainMenuPage().id` for `Navigator.pushNamed(..., MainMenuPage ().id)`, I prefer to use the `MainMenu.id`.

In the MainMenuPage page file, this currently looks like:

```
class MainMenuPage extends StatelessWidget {
    const MainMenu();
    static String id = 'main-menu-id'; // added by me, but not "enforced" through dart logic
}
```

I am aware that the flutter-way of Widget-Stacking is composition over inheritance. Still, I was wondering why I cannot create a superclass of all my pages to force them to implement this static variable.

In my imagination this would be looking like this:

```
abstract class MyAppPage() {
    static String id; 
}

class NotAbstractPage() extends StatelessWidget implements MyAppPage {
   static String id = 'foobar'; // this line is enforced through the quasi-interface
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach currently does not work in Dart. How could one make this work with some interfacy-ish mechaning?

Comment: You can't do it with `static` members because Dart does not treat them as part of the class interface. `static` members are equivalent to globals with a different scope.

Comment: Yes, it seems like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can force your pages to implement the variable in your superclass but it shouldn't be a static variable  like this :

```
abstract class MyAppPage {

      late String id ;

  }
```

if you Implement this class without overriding this variable it will give you an error :

[image]

after overriding it:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I want to force the implementation of an abstract variable... Thanks for your effort though